# makefile cd into dir and execute command

Tags: makefile

I have several AWS lambda functions which i want to build and deploy and have the following `Makefile`

```
#!/bin/bash
#SHELL:=/bin/bash --login
functions = $(sort $(dir $(wildcard */)))

define deploy
  cd $1 && npm deploy-dev
endef

deploy:
    $(foreach fn,$(functions),$(eval $(call deploy,$(fn))))
```

Basically each function is a node.js project that has the following entry in the package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "deploy-dev": "npm build && rm -rf node_modules && npm i --production  --legacy-bundling && AWS_PROFILE=dev SLS_DEBUG=* sls deploy --stage dev --region us-east-1"
```

cd into `dir` and running `npm deploy-dev` works as expected, but how to automate this?

i get an error:

```
➜  new_ingest git:(feature/organise) ✗ make deploy                                                                                                    (git)-[feature/organise] 
Makefile:11: *** missing separator. Stop.
```

Comment: which is line 11 in the Makefile?

Comment: is just an empty line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For purposes of finding the problem, we can reduce it to one function, changing this:

```
deploy:
    $(foreach fn,$(functions),$(eval $(call deploy,$(fn))))
```

to this:

```
deploy:
    $(eval $(call deploy,foo))
```

(where `foo/` is one of your directories.) Now we can see the problem. The `$(call ...)` part expands to `cd foo && npm deploy-dev`. It's a command to be passed to the shell, mot to be interpreted by Make. So when you tell Make to `eval` it, Make says *"this is gibberish".* If you remove the `eval`, it works.

Restoring the `foreach` causes a problem: all of the commands are concatenated into a single line (`cd foo && npm deploy-dev  cd bar && npm deploy-dev ...`). To solve this you could hack `deploy`:

```
define deploy
  cd $(1) && pwd ; cd - ;
endef
```

or you could revise the scheme to give each function its own rule.